# What is a numerical proof that matrix multiplication is associative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I recently watched a 3b1b video on matrix multiplication and he ended the video with a proof that matrix multiplication is associative, but without any numerical or algebraic proof.

I did the matrix multiplication for $(AB)C$, where I first multiplied a $2\times2$ matrix $(a,b,c,d)$ by the $2\times2$ matrix $(e,f,g,h)$ and I multiplied the product by the $2\times2$ matrix $(i,j,k,l)$ and I got a different result (in hindsight, quite obviously) than when I used the same matrices and started with $(BC)$.

I assume this has to do with the non-commutativity of matrices, but then what's the point of the parentheses, and what was he talking about when he said he tried to work the proof out numerically? What was he attempting to do?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Matrix_Multiplication_is_Associative or https://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk05/05_associativity_of_matrix_multiplication.html

Comment: When you "used the same matrices and started with (BC)", did you continue with A(BC) or with (BC)A ? The former should give the same result as your previous calculation of (AB)C; if it didn't, then you just made a computation error. On the other hand, (BC)A gives a different result, because of non-commutativity of matrix multiplication.

Comment: The vast majority of math videos are unfortunately only good for entertainment.

Comment: @Peter But the proof presented, in this case, is perfectly valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start here.

> What was he talking about when he said he tried to work the proof out numerically?

Matrix multiplication is a process that can be applied to two compatible matrices. For matrices $A,B$ of sizes $m \times p$ and $p \times q$ respectively, $AB$ is the $m \times q$ matrix whose entries are given by
$$
[AB]_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^p a_{ik}b_{kj};\quad  i = 1,\dots,m, \quad j = 1,\dots, p
$$
Note that this product is defined for a *pair* of matrices. If we want to multiply matrices $A,B,C$ (where $A,B$ have the same shapes as before and $C$ has size $q \times n$) in the order $ABC$, there are two ways that we can interpret this expression. Either we can say that $ABC = (AB)C$, whose entries are given by
$$
[(AB)C]_{ij} = \sum_{\ell=1}^q [AB]_{i,\ell}C_{\ell j} = \sum_{\ell =1}^q \left(\sum_{k=1}^p a_{ik}b_{k \ell}\right)c_{\ell j}, \quad i = 1,\dots,m, \quad j = 1,\dots, n,
$$
or we could say that $ABC = A(BC)$, whose entries are given by
$$
[A(BC)]_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^p a_{ik}[BC]_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^p a_{ik}\left( \sum_{\ell=1}^q b_{k\ell }c_{\ell j}\right), \quad i = 1,\dots,m, \quad j = 1,\dots, n.
$$
What we want to show is that these two formulas give the same answer. In other words, $A(BC) = (AB)C$, which means that the expression $ABC$ can be interpreted unambiguously. That is, matrix multiplication is **associative**.

For an example of a non-associative operation, consider the fact that $A - B - C$ really refers to the expression $(A - B) - C$, which is **not** the same as the expression $A - (B - C)$.

---

When $A,B,C$ are all $2 \times 2$, here's what that looks like in its fully expanded form. The pairwise products are
$$
AB = 
\pmatrix{
a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} & 
a_{11}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{22}\\
a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21}&
a_{21}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{12}},
\\
BC = 
\pmatrix{
b_{11}c_{11} + b_{12}c_{21} & 
b_{11}c_{12} + b_{12}c_{22}\\
b_{21}c_{11} + b_{22}c_{21}&
b_{21}c_{12} + b_{12}c_{12}}.
$$
The fact that $(AB)C = A(BC)$ amounts to
$$
\pmatrix{
a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} & 
a_{11}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{22}\\
a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21}&
a_{21}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{12}} 
\pmatrix{c_{11} & c_{12}\\ c_{21} & c_{22}} = \\
\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}}
\pmatrix{
b_{11}c_{11} + b_{12}c_{21} & 
b_{11}c_{12} + b_{12}c_{22}\\
b_{21}c_{11} + b_{22}c_{21}&
b_{21}c_{12} + b_{12}c_{12}}.
$$